# What does this error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x30d51fff8)" mean? How do I fix it

Tags: swift, uikit

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var triviaLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var trueButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var falseButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    
    var quiz = [Question(text: "Blah blah", answer: "True"),
                Question(text: "Ha ha", answer: "True"),Question(text: "Bruh bruh", answer: "False")]
    
    var questionNumber = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateQuestion()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func answerButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle
        let actualAnswer = quiz[questionNumber].answer
        if userAnswer == actualAnswer {
            
        } else {
            
        }
        
        if questionNumber < quiz.count-1 {
            questionNumber += 1
        }else {
            questionNumber = 0
        }
        updateQuestion()
    }
    
    func updateQuestion() {
        triviaLabel.text = quiz[questionNumber].text // Get the error here
        updateQuestion()
    }
}
```

The build succeeds and the app launches but there comes a blank screen and the error occurs. I tried mapping the label again with the storyboard. I speculate that there is some problem with the label declaration or connection.

Comment: Don't call `updateQuestion` from within `updateQuestion`. Infinite recursion is bad.

Comment: The error message you get when you crash is often not very informative. In broad terms, it means your code tried to read/write to an invalid memory address. As HangarRash points out in their comment, your updateQuestion function has infinite recursion, which will cause a **stack overflow**. (Fitting for this site, innit?)

Comment: Thank you. I understood the issue. This helped. @DuncanC Indeed stack overflowed.